# Zero Temperature non relativistic fermionic propagator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, integration

As an assigmente i am trying to prove the following result:

$$\hbar \int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\omega0^+}}{\hbar\omega-\zeta(\vec{k})+isgn(\omega)\eta}=i\theta(-\zeta(\vec{k}))$$

Where $\zeta(\vec{k})=\frac{(\hbar k)^2}{2m}-\mu$, the $0^+$ is a convergence factor and the $\eta $ means you should deform the integration contour and the $\theta()$ is the Heaviside step function.
I am kinda lost where to start.
My initial guess is to split the integral according to the sign of $\omega$, performing integration with the residue theorem, closing one part of the ingtegral in the upper complex plane and the other half in the lower complex plane. Assuming what i have done is correct i end up with this :

$$I=i(e^{i(\zeta(\vec{k}-i\eta)0+}-e^{i(\zeta(\vec{k}+\eta)0^+})$$.

At this point i am unsure on how to get the result. Any input would be very helpful.

Comment: Note that $\exp(a0^+)=1$ for any $a\in\mathbb C$. Therefore, your expression vanishes, $I\equiv 0$.